# Database schema publishing with SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: sql-server, database, versioning

I've a question for you. We have built a software that has a single database for each customer. These databases are managed by SQL Server 2008. Now the problem is that when we build our software we, sometimes, need to change something on the schema (like adding table, modifying existing ones etc) and migrate these updates on all the customers' databases.

Now this task is accomplished by hand: we generate update scripts and then, using T-SQL, we update each database. This is ok for a small set of customer, but we are now becoming bigger and bigger and we really don't know how to face it. We found [Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/) and it seems interesting, but quite difficult for us to learn in this exact moment.

Do you have any other trick?

Thanks a lot,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Redgate Sql Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm)

Comment: Do you use it? Is that ok for what i asked? Thanks!

Comment: This tool is absolutly perfect!